# how to attach overlay to detected object using android and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I'm writing an android app using OpenCV for my masters that will be something like a game. The main goal is to a detect a car in selected area. The "prize" will be triggered randomly while detecting cars. When the user will hit the proper car I want to display a 3D object overlay on the screen and attach it to the middle of the car and keep it there so when the user will change the angle of his view on the car, the object will also be seen from diffrent angle.

at the moment I have EVERYTHING beside attaching the object. I've created detection, I'm drawing the 3D overlay, I've created functions that allow me to rotate the camera etc. BUT I do not have any clue how can I attach the overlay to the specific point. Cause I don't have this I have no point to recalculate the renderer to change the overlay perspective.

Please, I really need some help, even a small idea will be fine:

How can I attach the overlay to the specific in real world

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I couldn't comment. Need at least 50 points to do that ... :P )

I assume your image of the car is coming from a camera feed and you are drawing 3d car in opengl. If so, then you can try this:

- You set the pixel format of the opengl layer as RGBA_8888, so that you can set the background of the opengl camera as a transparent color.
- You take a relative layout as layout of your activity.
- first you add the opencv camera layout to it as full height and width.
- then you add opengl layer as full height and width.
- you get the position of the real car from opencv layer as pixel value or something you did.
- then scale it to your opengl parameters so that you can draw it on the right spot.

it worked for me. hope it works for you too.